# Getting Netbeans Java program to compile

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

I'm new to java, and I've been trying to get my program to compile using Netbeans. HelloWorldApp.java uses the Greeter class in Greeter.java. I keep getting errors and I can't figure it out. I understand that you have to include "packages" or something. I don't have a lot of experience with Netbeans either. But I would love for this to work.

Here is the HelloWorldApp.java:

```
package helloworldapp;
import Greeter
public class HelloWorldApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Greeter myGreeterObject = new Greeter();
        myGreeterObject.sayHello();
    }
}
```

And here is Greeter.java:

```
public class Greeter
{
    public void sayHello()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello, World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What package is `Greeter` in? In the same project? What errors are you getting? Are we supposed to guess?

Comment: Sorry. Yes it's in the same project. The errors i'm getting are: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous tree type: Greeter.<error>
 at helloworldapp.HelloWorldApp.main(HelloWorldApp.java:7)
Java Result: 1

Comment: `import Greeter` needs a semicolon. At first blush everything else looks fine.

Comment: @DrewKennedy `import Greeter` would be importing a class from the same package, which is either unnecessary or wrong. Or both.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Sure, but that's not causing the error. Likely is the semicolon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the first line of `Greeter` to

```
package helloworldapp;
```

And then remove

```
import Greeter
```

from `HelloWorldApp`. You only need to import classes that are in other packages. Also, an import line is terminated with a semicolon. Finally, `import` is always optional and a convenience for the developer; as an example,

```
import java.util.Calendar;
```

Allows you to write

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

But, without the import you could still use

```
java.util.Calendar cal = java.util.Calendar.getInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the Greeter class in the same folder (i.e. package) as the other file and remove the "import Greeter" statement. You should put every class in a package as you did with the HelloWorldApp class.

If you leave classes without package (i.e. in the root folder) you cannot import them.

Answer (score 0):

As long as both are in the same package (folder) there will be no need for the "import Greeter" statement, this should fix it, hope this helps!